# Clearing the browser cache not solving site issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, caching

I developed a site using simple HTML, CSS, javascript and PHP as backend language. Lately there has been an issue, the site seemed to be not loading any stylesheets, but there was no error in console that..the css files were loading normally. I tried clearing the cache and it solved the problem. But i faced the issue once again. Again i tried clearing the cache but the problem dint get fixed. I tried disabling the cache in devTools, still no solution. The site is continuously taking inputs from the cache, even if I try changing something for example the font size or anything it reflect the changes. Can somebody please give me a solution. Here is a screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqd6N.png)

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<html lang="en">



    <head>

      <!-- Basic -->
      <title>Margo | Home</title>

      <!-- Define Charset -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <!-- Responsive Metatag -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

      <!-- Page Description and Author -->
      <meta name="description" content="Margo - Responsive HTML5 Template">
      <meta name="author" content="GrayGrids">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

      <!-- Revolution Slider -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/settings.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

      <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

      <!-- Slicknav -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slicknav.css" media="screen">

      <!-- Margo CSS Styles  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/customstyles.css" media="screen">

      <!-- Responsive CSS Styles  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" media="screen">

      <!-- Css3 Transitions Styles  -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" media="screen">

      <!-- Color Defult -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red.css" media="screen" />

      <!-- Color CSS Styles  -->
      <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red.css" title="red" media="screen" />


    </head>
```

Comment: Can you show how you handle the loading of those styles? Some code or something

Comment: please see the updated part

Comment: You have added **css/colors/red.css** twice it seems..

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala thats not the case....i removed the extra link...but even if i delete few files the site loads normally. It is loading data completely from the cache

Comment: Do you actually want your page not to get cached?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Taken from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

i don't know weather it will work or not but give a try with pressing Ctrl+f5  once on browser :)

it will refresh a page with new code.